# Hide error labels shown with angularjs form validation after some time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-validation

I am using angularjs form validation for client side validation. I need to hide the labels which displaying with angularjs error form validation method, after 3 seconds, after message appear.

Html will look like this,

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="name" required>
    <label ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email">
    <label ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Looking for a general solution like custom directives or else.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So hide the error message after 3 seconds of form load?  Or of the message appearing?  Or something else?

Comment: after message appear

Comment: I suggest to use $timeout function in angularJS  (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) having timeout of 3 secs and then hide the label using ng-show or ng-hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a directive like this,

```
app.directive('timeoutHtml', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            onVisible: '=showModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(function() {
                return attrs.ngShow;
            }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                checkVisibility();
            });

            function checkVisibility() {
                if (element.is(':visible')) {
                    scope.$watch('onVisible', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                        console.log(newValue)
                        if (newValue === true) {
                            $timeout(function() {
                                scope.onVisible = false;
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    });

                }
            };

        }
    };
});
```

and changed html to this,

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate="">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="name" required="" />
        <label  timeout-html="" show-model="submitted" ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">You name is required.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" required />
        <label ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Plunker demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/P4uopx4MhOFEszXuuYyA?p=preview